# Probability of picking a certain option at least once in two tries

Tags: probability

I'm doing probability problem on Khan Academy and a little bit confused. The problem is following:

> Marvin lives in Stormwind City and works as an engineer in the city of
>   Ironforge. In the morning, he has $3$ transportation options
>   (teleport, ride a dragon, or walk) to work, and in the evening he has
>   the same $3$ choices for his trip home. If Marvin randomly chooses his
>   method of travel in the morning and in the evening, what is the
>   probability that he teleports at least once per day?

My answer was $1/9$ because morning probabilty of random choice of teleportation is $1/3$ and evening's $1/3$ either multiplying them leads to $1/9$ however the correct answer is $5/9$

[image: this is a diagram]

Comment: Your calculation gives the probability that he teleported to work *and* teleported back. That's what multiplying the probability of two events does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of of an event happening at least once in a sequence of independent events?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428496/probability-of-of-an-event-happening-at-least-once-in-a-sequence-of-independent)

Comment: You have listed the nine possible options.  How many of them involve teleporting at least once?

Answer (score 1):

It says "at least once," which means it could be in the morning *or* evening *or* both. There are $5$ choices that have at least one teleport in the day - rows $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $7$ in the list given - and there are nine total outcomes, so the answer is $5/9$.